# why is this not executing in vs code editor?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

```
public class binsearch {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arr[]={2,45,-21,56,23};
    int target=45;
    int answer=binarysearch(arr, target);
    System.out.println(answer);

}
static int binarysearch(int arr[],int target)
{

    int start=0;
    int end=arr.length-1;
    int mid=start+end/2;
    while(start<=end)
    {
    if(target<arr[mid])
    {
        mid=end-1;
    }
    else if(target>arr[mid])
    {
        mid=mid+1;
    }
    else
    {
        return mid;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

}

I have tried running this code multiple times but it just doesnt run. I dont think there is any problem with the logic for binary search in this code. Please do help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs. It has an infinite loop so it never terminates.

In order for a binary search to work. The array **must** be sorted in ascending order. So just sort the array before you do the binary search. Below code uses class `java.util.Arrays` to sort the array but you can sort it anyway you like. Just make sure that the array is sorted before you do the binary search.

Also, the calculation of `mid` needs to be inside the `while` loop because it always changes since its value is determined by the values of both `start` and `end` and those values are changed inside the `while` loop.

Note that I changed the name of the class so as to adhere to [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). The conventions make it easier for other people to read and understand your code.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinSearch {
    static int binarysearch(int arr[], int target) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length - 1;
        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + ((end - start) / 2);
            if (target < arr[mid]) {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (target > arr[mid]) {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
            else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {2, 45, -21, 56, 23};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int target = 45;
        int answer = binarysearch(arr, target);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

The `answer` is 3 because, after the sort, 45 is the second last element in the [sorted] array because it is the second largest number in the array.

If you want to search without sorting the array then a binary search is not appropriate.

Comment: If the element is not found, your code will also loop infinitely.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a detailed explaination ^_^

Comment: @RachelPeters you can show your appreciation by accepting my answer :-)